# Streaming through Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, streaming

I have built a streaming relay server using Tomcat.

Simple idea is: one client does a POST, another client does a GET. The servlet spawns off a Thread and does a simple byte shuffling until the InputSteam (from the POST) is empty. When done closes / answers both requests. All is fine and it works perfectly, BUT:

Tomcat seems to reuse request objects and even the InputStream objects! Every 10th POST or so, the InputStream can't be read because already closed. Having a closer look at the logs I realize that the exact same InputStream object was used (and thus closed) by an earlier request. Turns out even the HttpServletRequest object is the exact same.

What is going on here? Why is Tomcat reusing objects which obviously haven't been reset properly? I've tried it with version 7.0.29 and 6.0.16, same thing.

Comment: This kind of thing usually occurs when you retain a reference to a resource after the request has completed. Are you storing a reference to the request, response, or stream anywhere?

Comment: I did not cache any request or response object, but it turned out that the byte shuffling thread released the InputStream object a bit too late (after the request was already returned), so I assume this was the problem. While I agree that one should never cache these objects, the fact that Tomcat responds so poorly is a big disappointment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a resource-management problem (you have a thread holding an `InputStream` too long), you should be able to fix that: have the servlet that launched the thread (or submitted the task to an `Executor`... you *are* using any `Executor` for this, right?) wait for the thread to finish (or the `Future` to complete) and release its resources. If you post the code to your byte-pump thread (and relevant parts of the servlet(s)), I can show you how to improve them.

Comment: the solution was an easy one, the tough part was identifying the problem. I simply am using a little wrapper for each Input / OutputStream. Now my background thread only references the wrapper and never the stream directly and I can simply null out the references inside the wrapper before returning from the request (that background thread stopped shuffling by now anyways and is just about to clean up - which sometimes too a little too long).

Answer (score 0):

update:

turned out that my spawned off Thread (which obviously had a reference to the Input and OutputStreams) did not release those references in time always. Thanks, Christopher, for the pointer!

While I agree that caching these objects is very bad practice and one should never do that, it is quite a disappointment that Tomcat does react so poorly to it. I'd expect better of an app server of that maturity...

Comment: You *can* disable the reuse of these objects. The consequence is that Tomcat generates a whole lot more garbage and your performance will diminish due additional GC activity.

Comment: interesting. how do I disable that? In my case I only have few connections that shuffle a lot of data, so there's not that many objects to reuse anyways...

Comment: If you disable such re-use, it will negatively affect the performance of every request that you process... not just those where you retain references to the streams.

Comment: Look for "recycle" on the (Tomcat System Properties](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html) page. I can't remember if the streams get their own façades or if it's just the request and response objects. This might not protect you at all.